# How to assign PHP-variables by using two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for-loop which loops through two arrays.

My first one looks like this:

```
$pos = array("Yada Yada", "Boom Boom");
```

And the second one looks like this:

```
$pos_var_names = array("yada", "boom");
```

My goal is to use a for-loop to automatically loop through both arrays at the same time and for example set:

```
$yada = "Yada Yada";
```

How do I do this in the most efficient way?

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Have been coding for a couple of hours straight and I'm feeling a bit dizzy.

Best regards!

Comment: why using loop for an array that only has 2 elements?

Comment: @Akam http://sscce.org/ (well, it's not that great a sample, but nevertheless an example doesn't really need more than two elements in an array)

Comment: My array has far more elements than 2. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for-loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pos); $i++)
    ${$pos_var_names[$i]} = $pos[$i]; // variable variables
```

---

But it is more elegant like this:

```
extract(array_combine($pos_var_names, $pos));
```

This just makes an $varname => $pos array (see also the [documentation for `array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) which is then [`extract()'ed`](http://php.net/extract).

---

But generally, it's better to just have an associative array instead of using tons of variables. It just will fill your variable scope with useless variables which might conflict with other variables you have.

Comment: While this may be functionally correct, I would add more detail to explain what is going on for the OP (who is clearly learning). For example, links to the documentation, and what the result of  `array_combine()` will do given the OP's sample input. Also, why an approach like this is fundamentally flawed as well as answering the original question: *"My goal is to use a for-loop"*

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to know which syntax to use in specific situations. I figured your first alternative out but I didn't realize that it had to be { } around the variable.

Sometimes I use "My name is $name" and other times I use 'My name is '. $name .''. How to know which one to use at the right time?

Comment: @user2624679 both syntaxes do exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I know which one is the best in certain situations?

Comment: @user2624679 Personal preference? There's not really a reason for the one or the other.